# Oracle SQL different plan for same query on different environments

Tags: database, oracle, performance, database-performance

Two very similar environments, same database structure, one query, two execution plans: one with nested loops and indexes (fast), another with hash joins and full access (slow).

Which steps should I perform to find the cause of plans difference?

Comment: "very similar environments" != "exact environment".  Same oracle version?

Comment: and the data/stats - are they similar? 10 rows vs 10M?

Comment: Start with making sure that the statistics are up to date in both environments and that the tables have similar size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that the Database version is same on both env.:

`SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;`

2. And then check your table's statistics on both environments:

   `SELECT TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS, AVG_ROW_LEN, SAMPLE_SIZE,
   LAST_ANALYZED FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';`
3. If the statistics are different then run below script on both env.:

`BEGIN
EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('YOUR_SCHEMA','YOUR_TABLE',cascade=>TRUE);
END;`

Comment: Well, I was skeptical, but this really works. I've gathered statistics for all tables used in query, and plans become identical. However, **It's also important to check if all indexes are the same and all statistics is gathered recently.** Yesterday statistics != today statistics.

Comment: @sinedsem Yes, correct. Depend on the env. workload you can define, i.e. how many times a day need to gather the statistics.
The value `CASCADE` - determines whether or not index statistics are collected as part of gathering table statistics.